# Html file loading in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mern

I am trying to run my project but in this file only loading html file not loading on browser but it shows in inspect.

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYePd.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpMDx.png)

**index.js**

```
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");
var requests = require("requests");


const indexFile = fs.readFileSync("index.html", "utf-8");
const replaceVal = (tempVal,orgVal)=>{
    let temperature=tempVal.replace("{%tempval%}",orgVal.main.temp);
     temperature=temperature.replace("{%tempmax%}",orgVal.main.temp_max);
     temperature=temperature.replace("{%tempmin%}",orgVal.main.temp_min);
     temperature=temperature.replace("{%location%}",orgVal.name);
     temperature=temperature.replace("{%country%}",orgVal.sys.country);
     return temperature;

}

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  if (req.url == "/") {
    requests("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=akola&units=metric&appid=bbef5cbba9217c339e607bc503f4e700")
      .on("data",  (chunk) => {
        const objdata= JSON.parse(chunk);
        const arrData =[objdata];
        // console.log(arrData[0].main.temp);
        const realTimeData=arrData.map((val)=>replaceVal(indexFile,val))
        .join("");

        res.write(realTimeData);
        // console.log(realTimeData);

      })
      .on("end",  (err) =>{
        if (err) return console.log("connection closed due to errors", err);

       
      });
  }
});

server.listen(15000,"127.0.0.1");
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle ">
    <div class="card cb2" style="width: 18rem; ">
      <div class="card-body text-center text-light">
        <h3 class="card-title">{%location%},{%country%}</h3>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 " id="date">Web|Oct 23| 10:49 Am</h6>
        <div class="mt-5">
          <h5 class="card-title">{%tempval%} C</h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 ">Min {%tempmin%} C | Max {%tempmax%} C</h6>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <script>
  const curDate= document.getElementById("date");
  let weathercon = document.getElementById("weathercon");
  const temStatus = "Clouds";
  const getCurrentDay=()=>{
   var weekday = new Array(7);
   weekday[0]="Sunday";
   weekday[1]="Monday";
   weekday[2]="Tuesday";
   weekday[3]="Wednesday";
   weekday[4]="Thursday";
   weekday[5]="Friday";
   weekday[6]="Saturday";

   let CurrentTime = new Date();
  let day= weekday[CurrentTime.getDay()];
  return day;
  };

  const getCurrentTime = ()=>{
    var months=[
      "Jan",
      "Feb",
      "Mar",
      "Apr",
      "May",
      "June",
      "July",
      "Aug",
      "Sept",
      "Oct",
      "Nov",
      "Dec",
    ];

    var now = new Date();
    var month = months[now.getMonth()];
    var date = now.getDate();



    let hours= now.getHours();
    let mins= now.getMinutes();
    let perios= "AM";
    if (hours>11){
      perios="PM";
      if(hours>12)hours-=12;
    }
    if(mins<10){
      mins="0"+mins;
    }
return `${month} ${date} | ${hours}:${mins}${perios}`;
  };


  curDate.innerHTML=getCurrentDay()+" "+"|"+" "+getCurrentTime();
 </script>   

</body>

</html>
```

I was also tried to change the port number but still same. There is no any error in console also. Also i was tried to rendering a output using console.log and it shows. But on browser it not showing.

Comment: Add a `res.end()` inside the `on.("end")` statement and check if it works

Comment: Still same problem.